# installing stripe for VSC on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tar

I am following these directions:

> 1. Download the latest linux tar.gz file from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/latest
> 2. Unzip the file: `tar -xvf stripe_X.X.X_linux_x86_64.tar.gz`
> 3. Move `./stripe` to your execution path.

I downloaded the file in #1. I then unzipped it by right clicking on it and choosing unzip into a dir called stripe. This created a file called stripe in my stripe directory.

But how do I do step #3?

Comment: Isn’t this [the same question you asked yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373897/installing-stripe-cli-for-use-with-vsc-extension-with-homebrew-or-by-hand)?

Answer (score 0):

At this point don't worry about moving anything just `locate ./stripe` and run the command per your instructions using the full path shown from the output of `locate`.  That should finish the setup.  In the future I recommend using deb packages whenever they are available.

$`sudo apt install ./path/package_name.deb`

where path is the location of the deb package.

Answer (score 0):

This case (3rd step)we can follow the **./Stripe** comment.

- 3 step: ./stripe login

  ***Your pairing code is: hale-bonny-liking-wisdom
  This pairing code verifies your authentication with Stripe.
  Press Enter to open the browser or visit https://dashboard.stripe.com/stripecli/confirm_auth?t=xxxxxxxxxxxxx (^C to quit)

After log in you can access 90 days in CLI.

- 4.step: example ->   **./stripe plans list**
  **get all your plans.

can get the details based on stripe --help comment start with **./stripe**.

Comment: By "flow" do you mean "follow"?  What do you mean "accuses"?  Do you mean "use" or "access".  If you are capable, please [edit] your answer to be clearer and use better English.  Also, please take the [tour].